# Creating a Custom Notification Bar in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I need to get started with it.
What I want to do is create a notification bar(like Omega, Status Bar).

I really have no idea from where to get started.
I don't need any code(I try to make my own new code,however long it take), but idea to do it.

I want bar to have many many more features hence I need to create one from scratch.

Also, I want that whenever application's(other) want to show a notification it should come on mine bar.

Comment: Here is a [link to a similar question][1] that might get you closer to an answer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165767/how-to-develop-custom-status-bar-in-android-jellybean-4-2-2