# How to develop custom status bar in android JellyBean 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-source

I want to develop customized StatusBar. I know i am not the only one with this requirement. But still want to know the opinions.

- After lot of search on StackOverflow, i found that people have
  modified status bar using tools but thats not i need.
- I am bit looking into the direction of developing of my own Status
  Bar with my own branding and layouting of the system icons.
- Also i have seen on Google play store about having a customized status bar app like [omega status bar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.calsto.omega.statusbar) and couple more. I am looking for the same implementation.
  I also learnt that these kind of apps are installed on non-rooted device, the way i need and uses a "DISABLE OR MODIFY STATUS BAR" permission.
- I also have created some basic layout for status bar but don't know how to proceed further in making my status bar app and overriding the default status bar (Systemui.apk)

**Summary** - How can one develop its own status bar app in android pro-grammatically?.

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I could find:

- a ["How to Make a Custom Status Bar" site](http://www.techknow.me/forum/index.php?topic=343.0) that has a step by step (looks promising)

However it looks like you may need to alter the firmware

- [this link](http://www.mentby.com/Group/android-developers/override-the-status-bar.html) claims the only way to override the status bar is to change the android source code

I was also able to find this

- a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829309/how-to-create-a-custom-status-bar-in-android-common-for-all-activity-in-android?rq=1) that uses the full screen feature and then put a new psuedo status bar on top creating the illusion of an altered status bar

Still, there are already apps on the market that do this as you mentioned yourself. *So*, there is an answer out there, however IMHO it may not be worth the effort to implement unless it is integral to your app (however, I would not advise you to pursue making a copycat app unless it is for personal improvement/practice)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply @kylie-moden your second bullet point is helpfull , Still would like to know more on this, what others has to say on this.